# Regular expression grep ^[^a]*$

Tags: linux, grep, regular-expression

Inside this directory

```
mael@mael-HP:~/repertoireVide$
```

Is a file called MySQLServe containing the words violon and avion:

```
mael@mael-HP:~/repertoireVide$ cat MySQLServ
violon avion
```

Why would these grep command applied in the current directory

```
$ grep -r  ^[^a]*$

$ grep -r  '^[^a]*$'
```

Not give any output?

The ^ followed by [^a] should omit `avion` from the search, but the *$ part of the argument should accept any other word with any possible ending. Why is `violon` excluded here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not get any result because your regular expression, `^[^a]*$` (which should be quoted using single quotes as in your second attempt), matches lines that contains only non-`a` characters (or empty lines), and your text string is not empty and it does contain an `a`.

The `*` acts on the previous expression, `[^a]` in this case.  `[^a]*` will match zero or more non-`a` characters.  Since you anchor the expression to both start and end of the line around this, it rejects any line that contains the letter `a`.

To `grep` for lines that start with something that is not `a`, use

```
grep -r '^[^a]' .
```

Note that it is not necessary to explicitly match tho whole line, but if you want to do that, use

```
grep -r '^[^a].*$' .
```

`.*` matches zero or more of *any* character (including `a`).

To also get empty lines in the output (these obviously don't start with `a`):

```
grep -r -v '^a' .
```

That is, match an `a` at the start of a line and invert the sense of the match using `-v`.  This way you don't require any characters at all in a line (note that to match `[^a]`, there has to be at least one character), but if there are some, the first one shouldn't be an `a`.

To search for *words* that don't start with `a`, use

```
grep -r -w -o '[^a][[:alpha:]]*' .
```

That expression matches anything that starts with something other than `a`, and then continues with zero or more alphabetic characters.  The `-w` option to GNU `grep` restricts the matches to words, and the `-o` option asks `grep` to only extract the matching parts from each line.

Comment: Note that if you had the words in separate lines you would get the desired result (violon but not avion).